# Утечка памяти при работе с графикой

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

В общем, есть окно, где есть комбобокс с десятками ссылок на картинку весом ~2 мб и разрешением 5037x3657.

Каждое перелистывание картинок добавляет используемое озу к программе, вплоть до 2 ГБ...

Картинки я нигде не кеширую.

VM у меня при каждом изменении значения в ComboBox запрашивает Drawing.Image из класса:

```
  public ImageInfo CurrentImageInfo
    {
        get => _currentImageInfo;
        set
        {
            _currentImageInfo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentImageInfo));
            try
            {
                using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)CurrentImageInfo.GetMarkupedImage())
                {
                    ImageSrc = BitmapToImageSource(bitmap);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogMessage += "\n" + e;
            }
            ImageSource BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
            {
                return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                     bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                     IntPtr.Zero,
                     Int32Rect.Empty,
                     BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            }
        }
    }

 public Image GetMarkupedImage()
    {
        Image image;
        int x;
        int y;
        using (var srcImage = GetImageCopy())
        {
            image = MarkupDrawer.CreateImageWithBorder(srcImage, out x, out y);
        }
        using (var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            foreach (var person in Persons)
            {
                var newRec = MarkupDrawer.ScaleMarkup(person.Rectangle, x, y);
                MarkupDrawer.DrawMarkup(graphic, image, person.ToString(), newRec);
            }
        }
        return image;
    }

    Image GetImageCopy()
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        File.OpenRead(FilePath).CopyTo(memoryStream);
        return Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
    }
```

Вроде, ничего криминального не вижу в коде.

ImageSource не обладает методом Dispose.

Comment: То есть у вас есть окно с одним котролом Image и одним котролом ComboBox. При выборе какой-нибудь ссылки в ComboBox она у вас загружается в этот Image?

Comment: А, можете не отвечать... `var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();` - вот тут проблема. Вы поток не уничтожаете... Используйте `using` или вызывайте `Dispose()`

Comment: Не, похоче все таки в другом. Мне вот это помогло https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714841/image-loading-memory-leak-with-c-sharp . Оказывается, что я должен был хендлеры уничтожать WinApi функцией.

Comment: После использования этой API функции ОЗУ держится в приделах 250 МБ, а не уходит бесконечно в потолок.

Comment: если `public ImageInfo CurrentImageInfo` это свойство, то я к сожалению впервые вижу такой синтаксис (и оно у меня ожидаемо не компиллируется);   что за синтаксис `get => _currentImageInfo;`, разве можно объявлять функции внутри `set{...}` ? в чём магия?? :)

Comment: @Alias, body-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм...

Помог вот [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714841/image-loading-memory-leak-with-c-sharp) ответ.

Оказывается я должен был вызывать `WinApi` функцию `DeleteObject` и передавать ей на вход `bitmap.GetHbitmap()` .

Т.е правильный код без утечек выглядит так:

```
   public ImageInfo CurrentImageInfo
    {
        get => _currentImageInfo;
        set
        {
            _currentImageInfo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentImageInfo));
            try
            {
                using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)CurrentImageInfo.GetMarkupedImage())
                {

                  ImageSrc = BitmapToImageSource(bitmap);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogMessage += "\n" + e;
            }
            BitmapSource BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
            {
                var bmpPt = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
                var bitmapSource=Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap( bmpPt,IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
                bitmapSource.Freeze();
                NativeMethods.ReleaseHbitmap(bmpPt);
                return bitmapSource;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool) ]
        internal static extern bool ReleaseHbitmap(IntPtr value);
    }
```

После этого ОЗУ перестало уходить в потолок и держится в районе 250 мб.

Comment: Хех, даже не вчитывался в код) вы загружаете через Bitmap, а потом его конвертируете в BitmapSource? Так вы у Bitmap после создания BitmapSource вызывайте Dispose. А ещё проще создавайте и используйте `new BitmapImage(Uri)`, где Uri может быть и файлом и ссылкой. У вас же WPF в конце концов, зачем через Bitmap работать?)

Comment: А я над исходным изображением провожу манипуляции в памяти, не сохраняя промежуточный результат.

Comment: Какого рода? Работа с пикселями? Есть WritableBitmap. Изменять размер, форму и так далее? Есть TransformedBitmap. Хотите быструю операцию над пикселями? Работаете напрямую с массивом байт в обход таких классов - это в принципе актуально и для WinForm.

Comment: По координатам рисую прямоуголники.

Comment: Пожалуйста, есть DrawingImage.